# Check ftp upload with wget and retry if necessary

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, wget

I have a minor bash script loop I'm trying to learn and accomplish but it's giving me a hard time to comprehend with all the readings I've done.

I am uploading to a ftp server, then I want to check to see if the upload went through successfully by using wget spider method. If it returns OK then we're good, if not then I want to redo the ftp upload once more.

The code I have below are based on my research and learning from here. If I could be doing this better, please help me revise it so I can learn from it.

```
for ((i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++ )); 
do 
    wget_output=$(wget -q --spider "http://$FTP_HOST/test.jpg")
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; 
    then
        ftp -in $FTP_HOST <<ENDFTP
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASSWORD
binary
put dEdLWOcOfPRqBU1.mp4.jpg
bye
ENDFTP
        $i="1";
    else
        echo "SQL CODE HERE"    
    fi
done
```

The error when executing is:

```
line 28: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: i dont have anything for line 28

Comment: Perhaps my code could be confusing for a common loop. Any help with another setup would be greatly appreciated. I learn most of my stuff from applying the examples of my requirements. Reading other people's work is a little bit confusing :)

Comment: Sorry but the code you posted is not even long 28 lines. Could you please either post the full code or tell us which line is line 28. What do you mean with "I don't have nothing for line 28"?

Comment: I have removed the ftp part and now it's telling me that 

   ./testloop.sh
: command not found 13:

   

    #!/bin/bash
##test looping
##version 1

FTP_HOST=
FTP_USER=
FTP_PASSWORD=

i=0;
for ((i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++ )); do

wget_output=$(wget -q --spider "http://s1.server.com/test.jpg")
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; 
then
echo "have it"

i=1
else
 echo SQL CODE HERE
fi
done

Comment: Then edit your question. From you comment is again pretty difficult to see which line is line 13.

Comment: Perhaps not directly related to the error, but I don't think that this line: `$i="1";` is doing what you want it to.  You're probably looking for `i=1`, and what you *really* want is probably a while loop keying off of `$?`.

Comment: @blahdiblah Where would i put that? sorry i'm a noob

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have blanks before `ENDFTP`. A here-doc should be terminated by a line with just the keyword you choose.

Comment: The way I have my ENDFTP has never caused any issues. I erase a few blanks and it's still giving me the same error